# Interlock for GE PowerMark plus subpanel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, transfer-switch, inverter

I have a GE [TL412R1P](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-PowerMark-Plus-Outdoor-125-Amp-4-Space-8-Circuit-Single-Phase-Main-Lug-Circuit-Breaker-Panel-TL412R1P/100123400) subpanel and would like to use a 70 amp breaker for the inverter and another 30 amp for the generator as transfer switch to either accept power from a 30 amp max split phase power generator or a 70 amp max solar inverter into the breaker panel. Is there a breaker interlock that I can adapt like this to this panel? Like this one
[image]

I already have a [100 amp transfer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-100-Amp-240-Volt-Non-Fused-Emergency-Power-Transfer-Switch-TC10323R/100171587) switch to either accept power from utility or power generator. Don't really want to add another transfer switch of that type. The sub panel is actually going into the "generator" side of the transfer switch.

Comment: This is basically a "nothing" panel. It only has 4 spaces, so it is **only** the two breakers and nothing else. You are effectively using it as an A/B switch. While it may seem a bit crazy, if there is no listed interlock kit available then the most cost-effective thing may be to find the least expensive panel *even if it has a lot more spaces in it that you will never use* that has an interlock available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a breaker interlock that I can **adapt** like this to this panel?

#### NO!

Categorically and undeniably, NO! You cannot adapt or modify any UL Listed electrical equipment beyond what's listed in the instructions for installation and still have it meet the listing. To my knowledge, no breakers allow any sort of "adaptation" to let them fit into a panel they're not certified and listed for.

If it's discovered during an inspection, you'll fail the inspection.

If it's discovered during a post-fire investigation, you'll get your insurance claim denied.

Your best bet is to return the things you've purchased then, starting with the interlock that will meet your needs, work backwards to find a panel that it will fit in even if, as noted by manassehkatz (in his comment on the OP), that panel is *huge* in relation to your current requirements.

For example, the [Eaton BR816B100](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-BR-100-Amp-8-Space-16-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Breaker-Loadcenter-with-Cover-BR816B100/100163467) is an 8-space panel that can take the [BRMIKBR](https://www.eaton.com/us/en-us/skuPage.BRMIKBR.html), which is described as "*BR mechanical interlock kit,Used with BR backfed loadcenters*".

Comment: Thanks for the help, manassehkatz!

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad that you have the transfer switch to take care of the utility-side interlocking.  We can cross that biggie off the list.  Now...

Your requirement is bonkers, and reflects a lack of understanding of how solar works. (Or full understanding and a bizarre lack of specificity, considering how hard that understanding is to achieve).

### Solar can't do that!

Our AC power stuff runs on - guess what - AC power. Raw solar panels do not produce AC power.  So you have a **grid-tie inverter** in there to sync-lock to **the utility grid** and backfeed the utility grid when it is available.  That's great for rolling your electric meter backwards, *but it does not work during grid-down*. As a whole bunch of 1%ers found out when during Hurricane Sandy, when they decided to hunker down in their homes "since they had solar".

Further, a grid-tie inverter will not "power up and help" if they are connected to a generator.  They automatically detect that they are on a generator and "not on the grid", and will not energize. Therefore, Grid-tied inverters/solar are passively interlocked, and you do not need a mechanical interlock - they can freely share the bus with a generator. They just won't do anything.

---

The other major option is a **DC solar charge controller**, which charges a battery, coupled by an **AC inverter** to make AC off the battery. Almost without fail, the asker now whines about how they don't want a battery. This is usually fueled by misconceptions, which are curable... but I won't get into that here.

Now if that second one is what you're doing, well that's fine; and that's the case where you would need the interlock you're after. But I think if you understood that, you would have been more specific.  Also, I think it's a dumb requirement because it provides no way to charge the batteries from the generator. There are times you'd want that. You could add a battery charger circuit *also* interlocked with the solar, so it can't be on when the solar is on.

---

Now, remember those angry 1%ers?  They demanded development of a totally new kind of system, called a **"grid forming inverter"**. This thing is MAGIC.  It emulates the grid so exactly that it causes those "grid-tied" solar panels to power up and generate. And then, (in order to simulate the grid), the grid-forming inverter gulps up the surplus solar and uses it to recharge its own batteries.   Oh yes, batteries again!  A Grid-Forming Inverter requires batteries, will not work without it.  Again that doesn't necessarily mean the batteries need to be huge, they need to be there for stability.

On a grid-forming inverter you definitely don't want to interlock out the solar - you want them feeding the same bus.

### That inverter, though

Nothing easier. Replace the GE subpanel with a Siemens panel, and use an ECSBPK01 or ECSPBK02 interlock.  *Do not slap Siemens breakers into a GE panel unless you enjoy melted bus stabs*.  You can do the same trick with a  Square D "QO" (QO2DTI interlock) or Eaton "CH" panel (CHML interlock).

If you need to interlock one breaker with two other breakers, put the one in the middle and make a stack of ECSBPK02, QO2DTI or CHML interlocks.